# SELECT com varias tabelas retorna somente um projeto

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de gerencia de projetos, na pagina HOME vai aparecer todos projetos.
No mySQL tenho na tabela de PROJECTS o cliente e gerente de projeto guardados como ID de Usuario e de Cliente... que tem seus dados em outras tabalas CLIENTS e USERS.
Estou fazendo um SELECT em PHP no mySQL que deveria me retornar todos projetos, porem retorna somente um.

```
$sql = "SELECT projects.id P_ID, projects.gerente P_GERENTE, projects.cliente P_CLIENTE, projects.nome P_NOME, projects.area P_AREA, projects.data_final_plan P_DATA, users.nome U_NOME, users.sobrenome U_SOBRENOME, clients.nome C_NOME FROM projects INNER JOIN users ON projects.gerente = users.id INNER JOIN clients ON projects.cliente = clients.id";
```

Alguem sabe porque? acho que pelo projects.gerente = users.id e projects.cliente = clients.id...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acho que porque esta ID=1 CLIENTE=2 GERENTE=1 nao aparece e ID=1 CLIENTE=1 GERENTE=1 e esse aparece!!!
Preciso fazer que o SELECT retorne sem comparar se o ID do gerente é igual ao ID do cliente!

Comment: Como estão as tabelas 'clients' e 'users'? Você fez as FK delas com a tabela 'projects'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta trocar os INNER por LEFT

Ex:

```
$sql = "SELECT projects.id P_ID, 
           projects.gerente P_GERENTE, 
           projects.cliente P_CLIENTE, 
           projects.nome P_NOME,
           projects.area P_AREA, 
           projects.data_final_plan P_DATA, 
           users.nome U_NOME, 
           users.sobrenome U_SOBRENOME, 
           clients.nome C_NOME
      FROM projects 
      LEFT JOIN users   ON projects.gerente = users.id 
      LEFT JOIN clients ON projects.cliente = clients.id";
```

Comment: Perfeito, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Segue o link com a diferença entre eles.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/118352

marque como resolvido caso tenha resolvido seu problema, obrigado amigo.